# Blank space on top of a video cover (only in safari, not chrome)

Tags: html, css, video, cover

I have a problem with a video cover for a website, but only when I opened it on Safari. There is a black space between the top and the video that I can't remove.

There is the code and an image down below:

```css
  video {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 30%;
  display: table;
  background: rgb(242, 242, 242) url('images/inicio.png') center bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  z-index: 1;
```

```html
<div>
  <video autoplay loop poster="images/inicio.png"> 
    <source src="video/video.webm" type="video/webm"> 
    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
    </video>
</div>
```

This is the website to see the code:
http://josefinaechenique.esy.es/videos.html

The image[image: here]

Comment: Can you provide some more code? I see you have a header above the video, more code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The `display:table` from the `video`tag seems to be the issue causing the big space there. Removing it should solve it

Comment: Have you tried giving it another type of `display` ?

Comment: I tried them all. Still not working. It's weird because when I'm on Live Preview on Safari and I delete the display, it gets fixed, but as soon as I save it, the problem goes back.